# Jenkins, Maven and semantic versioning: How to increment either the major or minor version

Tags: maven, jenkins, semantic-versioning

At our work we release and deploy our components via a Jenkins job. The problem with this is that it only increments the "patch" version number (major.minor.patch, e.g. 4.2.1 goes to 4.2.2). What I would like is to make the job tell maven that this is a "minor" release (4.2.1 -> 4.3.0), a "major" release (4.2.1 -> 5.0.0) or patch release (default  behaviour).

The interface to Jenkins to pass parameters to maven is straightforward but are there any commands to make maven update the minor or major version without having to explicitly state what version (and development version) you need. Since it can do the patch version updating so easily I'm hoping there is command to do the same for the minor or major version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `mvn` and the release plugin, you could easily update the version. You can do:

```
mvn release:update-versions
```

For more options, check the [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/update-versions.html).

Comment: Thanks. But this will only increment the "patch" number. I'm wondering if the only solution is have in the Jenkins release job a texfield prompt when you hit build. But then you'll need to know what the current version is etc. Prone to too much human error.

Comment: Yes you need a textfield in the UI. If you use the jenkins release plugin, you can actually specify that information.

Comment: I don't get the problem; the maven release will turn a snapshot version into a release version (1.0.5-SNAPSHOT -> 1.0.5) and then increment to the next snapshot version after it is done (1.0.6-SNAPSHOT). At this point you are free to turn that version into anything you want, so you can manually change the poms to be version 1.1.0-SNAPSHOT.

Comment: Hi Gimby. What I would like is it to go from 1.0.5-SNAPSHOT and have choice depending on what the development cycle was during this SNAPSHOT phase. For instance (roughly in line with semantic versioning) if we had interface changes to the client then we would say that we want a "major" release deployed (1.0.5-SNAPSHOT goes to 2.0.0 is released and deployed, then the trunk is now 2.0.1-SNAPSHOT). Similarly, for a "minor" release we would like it go something like: 1.0.5-SNAPSHOT -> (minor release) 1.1.0 -> 1.1.1-SNAPSHOT. For a "patch" release we just do the normal mvn release:release.

Comment: So you define the version after / at the same time as the actual release ?

Answer (score 1):

It may help someone lately. We use [Maven Build Helper](https://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/) plugin as below:

Minor release:

```
mvn build-helper:parse-version versions:set -DnewVersion=\${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.\${parsedVersion.nextMinorVersion}.0 versions:commit
```

Major release:

```
mvn build-helper:parse-version versions:set -DnewVersion=\${parsedVersion.nextMajorVersion}.0.0 versions:commit
```

Patch release:

```
mvn build-helper:parse-version versions:set -DnewVersion=\${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.\${parsedVersion.minorVersion}.\${parsedVersion.nextIncrementalVersion} versions:commit
```

Comment: works great - this should be the accepted answer imo

Comment: Does the plugin also support committing and pushing the new version?
This is my cycle:

state: 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
1. mvn versions:set -DremoveSnapshot -DgenerateBackupPoms=false
state: 1.0.0
2. mvn deploy
3. mvn build-helper:parse-version versions:set -DnewVersion=\${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.\${parsedVersion.minorVersion}.\${parsedVersion.nextIncrementalVersion}-SNAPSHOT versions:commit
state: 1.0.1-SNAPSHOT


commit & push should be done by github action